# Kotlin how to enumerate each line in a recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i'm using Kotlin and in a recyclerView I need to enumerate each cell that loads (1, 2, 3, etc). I can do this in IOS by adding the following under cellForRowAt:

```
cell!.cellCount.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
```

I haven't been able to find the equivalent for Kotlin, any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to list all items in the RecyclerView? Aren't you supposed to have a list associated to your adapter already?

Comment: @Nicolas yes, i have an array that loads from Firebase. I have a textView that is going to display the number of the cell. So if the query loads 30 cells, it's a lot easier for the user to scroll down to see the number of cells. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my code with the following.

**Inside viewHolder**

```
var cellCount = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cellCountLbl)
```

**Inside onBindViewHolder**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val indexRow = position + 1 
        holder.cellCount.text = indexRow.toString()
        holder.bindPatList(youArray[position])
}
```

Everything is working as expected. Thank you